# ArcGIS API for Python: AttributeError: module 'brotli' has no attribute 'error'

Tags: arcgis-pro, arcgis-python-api, arcgis-notebook

```
from arcgis.gis import GIS
```

when run in ArcGIS Pro 2.6 notebook results in long error message (below).

What might be wrong?

Note that *import arcpy* works without difficulties.

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
In  [3]:
Line 1:     from arcgis.gis import GIS

File C:\Program Files\ArcGIS\Pro\bin\Python\envs\arcgispro-py3\lib\site-packages\arcgis\__init__.py, in <module>:
Line 3:     from . import (features, geoanalytics, geocoding, geometry)

File C:\Program Files\ArcGIS\Pro\bin\Python\envs\arcgispro-py3\lib\site-packages\arcgis\features\__init__.py, in <module>:
Line 21:    from .feature import Feature, FeatureSet, FeatureCollection

File C:\Program Files\ArcGIS\Pro\bin\Python\envs\arcgispro-py3\lib\site-packages\arcgis\features\feature.py, in <module>:
Line 16:    from arcgis.gis import Layer

File C:\Program Files\ArcGIS\Pro\bin\Python\envs\arcgispro-py3\lib\site-packages\arcgis\gis\__init__.py, in <module>:
Line 29:    from arcgis.gis._impl._con._helpers import _is_http_url

File C:\Program Files\ArcGIS\Pro\bin\Python\envs\arcgispro-py3\lib\site-packages\arcgis\gis\_impl\_con\__init__.py, in <module>:
Line 1:     from ._connection import Connection

File C:\Program Files\ArcGIS\Pro\bin\Python\envs\arcgispro-py3\lib\site-packages\arcgis\gis\_impl\_con\_connection.py, in <module>:
Line 23:    import requests

File C:\Program Files\ArcGIS\Pro\bin\Python\envs\arcgispro-py3\lib\site-packages\requests\__init__.py, in <module>:
Line 43:    import urllib3

File C:\Program Files\ArcGIS\Pro\bin\Python\envs\arcgispro-py3\lib\site-packages\urllib3\__init__.py, in <module>:
Line 7:     from .connectionpool import HTTPConnectionPool, HTTPSConnectionPool, connection_from_url

File C:\Program Files\ArcGIS\Pro\bin\Python\envs\arcgispro-py3\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py, in <module>:
Line 39:    from .response import HTTPResponse

File C:\Program Files\ArcGIS\Pro\bin\Python\envs\arcgispro-py3\lib\site-packages\urllib3\response.py, in <module>:
Line 155:   class HTTPResponse(io.IOBase):

File C:\Program Files\ArcGIS\Pro\bin\Python\envs\arcgispro-py3\lib\site-packages\urllib3\response.py, in HTTPResponse:
Line 377:   DECODER_ERROR_CLASSES += (brotli.error,)

AttributeError: module 'brotli' has no attribute 'error'
```

Comment: Can you import `brotli` directly and see if the `error` class is available? Just open a python console in Pro and type `import brotli` and then call `brotli.error()`. It should just return `Error()`